# Jquery scroll 100% height div

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

I'll have many divs with 100vh height, like #pg1, #pg2 stacked on top of each other. Then if I scroll down just a little bit or press an arrow button (link with a image that will be in the right corner) it will position the other div to occupy 100% of the page smoothly.

EDIT: Something like this (not exactly): http://jsfiddle.net/wofbbzjy/

```
<div id="pg1">Teste</div>
<div id="pg2">Teste</div>
<div id="pg3">Teste</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var content_height = $(document).height();
        var content_scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var percentage_value = content_scroll_pos * 100 / content_height;

        if(percentage_value >= 0){
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: $('#pg2').position().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```
#pg1, #pg2 {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
#pg2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#pg3 {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I don't have idea how do i set jquery to do what I want

Comment: I tried something like this but it's not what i want http://jsfiddle.net/wofbbzjy/

Comment: @user3417825 There's a reason why direct links to jsFiddle are not allowed without including code inside your question. I've added the code blocks from the linked fiddle to your question, please make sure to do the same from now on.

Answer (score 0):

What is your question? Do you want to know how to do this -> making the 100vh pages slide over each other on scroll?

### EDIT

Okay. So this is what you could do ( maybe there's a better way ):

1. Make the body overflow: hidden;
2. Position the first div fixed and 100vh.
3. Make the other divs relative and position them below each other( not stacked )
4. Give the divs a different z-index so they align on top of each other.
5. Then use jQuery to lock it on top of the page by changing the css position to fixed when the Y position of the div is 0.

( by the way, there are a lot of open source projects out there that do exactly this for you. I would highly recommend checking them out )

Comment: Please make it an answer, not a question

Comment: what's the name of these projects?

Comment: can you post an jsfiddle example? I couldn't do this

Comment: I can't at the moment because I am going to sleep... Would recommend curtain.js to you. If you haven't solved it tomorrow let me know. I'll write a fiddle ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/LBBO/dj0cv286/1/

```
var visible = null;
function scrollTo(element){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($(element).position().top)}, 'slow');
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    visible = $('div').first();
    $(window).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 38) {
            visible = visible.prev();
            scrollTo(visible);
        }
        if(e.which == 40) {
            visible = visible.next();
            scrollTo(visible);
        }
    });
});
```